# How to share downloaded huggingface models among users?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, nfs, huggingface-hub

I'd like several users to share downloaded models, such that when any of the users downloads a model, e.g. using

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name)
```

the other users would be able to use it as well for inference, without having to download it again. The users would all be using linux, but may use different hosts, have different python environments and package versions, etc.

I'd like to know if the following solution will work:
Creating a shared NFS mount, e.g. `/models` and mount it on all hosts. Then, for each user, symlink their HF cache hub dir to a shared path. E.g.
`ln -s /models ~/.cache/huggingface/hub`.

I don't want to symlink `~/.cache/huggingface/`, since it also contains a personal HF token, and custom code in `modules`.

Assuming we can configure file permissions properly, will this work as expected or could there still be issues? E.g.:

- conflicts between different versions of packages, virtualenv/conda envs etc. between users
- file locking issues

Comment: Hmmm SO moderators, how is the question opinion based? =) It is lacking clarity but surely not opinion based. The solution is going to be saving with `model.save_to_disk` and `AutoModel.from_pretrained(..., local_files_only=True)`.

Comment: @alvas The initial revision asked _"If so, what would be a good alternative for sharing models?"_ Also, it wasn't closed by a moderator.

Comment: @dimid, if you do some edits to give a little more clarity and ask the question at the start/end "How to share huggingface models among users without using Huggingface Hub?", then we could help you get the question reopened and get you a clear answer =)

Comment: Thank you @alvas. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I was trying out some of these model ingress/egress earlier today and documented some steps here https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/how-to-use-peft-base-merged-models-in-offline-mode/78343

While we wait for re-open here, feel free to go to the HF forum and see if the steps there help.

Comment: Did you try docs? https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/cache